# Connect to Office365 via IMAP Too Many Login Failures - Basic VS Modern Auth

Tags: oauth, office365, imap

Have tried many variations of the below to attempt to connect to an office365 mailbox via PHP however having great difficulty.

```
    $user = 'user@domain.com';
    $pass = 'pass';
    $hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
    $m = imap_open($hostname, $user, $pass, NULL, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI'));
```

Tried with validate novalidate disable_authenticator and user string in hostname lots of variations of above however keep getting too many login failures error for above. I thought I was locked out which seems logical due to the error however new accounts seem to do the same thing first time and leaving it a day doesn't change anything. I have also made sure IMAP is enabled for users and whitelisted IPS within security of office 365.

After taking a step back and trying to just connect via Thunderbird I also cannot connect so am thinking it may be something else wrong here. I'm reading articles about basic authentication getting phased out for IMAP and POP so wondering how would one attempt this with Modern Auth with PHP?

Comment: I doubt anyone has implemented MS Modern Auth with PHP.  It’s based on OAuth2, and php_imap’s library doesn’t support this. Someone may be able to chime in with a more modern library (php_imap wraps an extremely old C library).  You’d still be reinventing the wheel though: microsoft supports a variety of programming languages with their own authentication library, but PHP is not one of them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview

Comment: Ah yeah fair enough, for now I just enabled basic auth for that single user and it worked so defo the auth thing. Bit worried support is ending for basic auth however so need to consider something like that for when that happens.